# FB meta tags issue - debugger says meta tags are in the body instead of the head

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an issue with facebook. When i'm looking my site's code in inspect element everything is fine. But facebook reads it wrongly. For example this post: http://aww.ge/ratom-asxams-es-kaci-mwerebis-sawinaaghmdego-spreis-windaze-imitom-rom-geniosia1/

In first 3 lines everything is fine, but fb reads:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<p>&#65279;
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header.php was saved in BOM.
This was main proble, after I fixed this, everything is OK.